# How to perform division in Go

Tags: math, go, floating-point, integer-division

I am trying to perform a simple division in Go.

```
fmt.Println(3/10)
```

This prints 0 instead of 0.3. This is kind of weird. Could someone please share what is the reason behind this? i want to perform different arithmetic operations in Go.

Thanks

Comment: Reading [The Go Blog: Constants](https://go.dev/blog/constants) might help anyone who is facing this for the first time.

Answer (score 123):

The operands of the binary operation `3 / 10` are untyped constants.  The specification  [says this about binary operations with untyped constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions)

> if the operands of a binary operation are different kinds of untyped constants, the operation and, for non-boolean operations, the result use the kind that appears later in this list: integer, rune, floating-point, complex.

Because `3` and `10` are untyped integer constants, the value of the expression is an untyped integer (`0` in this case).

To get a floating-point constant result, one of the operands must be a floating-point constant.  The following expressions evaluate to the untyped floating-point constant `0.3`:

```
3.0 / 10.0
3.0 / 10
3 / 10.0
```

When the division operation has an untyped constant operand and a typed operand, the typed operand determines the type of the expression. Ensure that the typed operand is a `float64` to get a `float64` result.

The expressions below [convert](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) `int` variables to a `float64` to get the `float64` result `0.3`:

```
var i3 = 3
var i10 = 10
fmt.Println(float64(i3) / 10)
fmt.Println(3 / float64(i10))
```

[Run a demonstration playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Uy0yTzbyAKh).

Note: The numeric literals `10.0` and `3.0` are untyped floating-point constants, not `float64`.  The expressions `i3 / 10.0` and `3.0 / i10` evaluate to the integer `0` because the typed operand (`i3` and `i10`) determine the type of the result.

Comment: i am taking input assuming it is percentage. For eg If the user gives 30, i have to perform 30/100 * somenumber. The input will always be an integer. How to perform division in this scenario ?

Comment: i tried fmt.Println(float64(3/10)) but it gives me 0

Comment: @VrushankDoshi: `fmt.Println(float64(3) / float64(10))` gives `0.3`.

Comment: Please edit your answer because `3 / 10.0` doesn't work, as mentioned by @robstarbuck 's answer.

Comment: @BaytaDarell This is my usecase [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/uwoKFmTWx02). Can you explain why it works like that?

Comment: @FederickJonathan `3 / 10.0` does work. See updated answer for information on your playground example.

Comment: NOTE:
`fmt.Println(i3 / 10.0)`
`fmt.Println(3.0 / i10)`

Will NOT work and you still need to cast to the float.