# How to divide a float in go

Tags: go

First of all i'm new to programming, and i have problem.
I'm trying to take 1/4 from a float but it doesn't work (it  has to be a float this is just an easier example).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    a float64
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("digit")
    fmt.Scan(&a)

    s := a * (1 / 4)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

If the input is 100 it returns 0.

Comment: The constant expression `(1/4)` evaluates to zero.  See question [How to perform division in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32815400/5728991) for more info.

Comment: nice job on the completeness of your example @PunPun - I wish we saw more such minimal, verifiable examples on SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dividing two integers, not floats. The fact that you later assign it to `float64` changes nothin. You need to use decimal point in at least one value to inform Go compiler it should do floating point division:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    a float64
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("digit")
    fmt.Scan(&a)

    s := a * (1.0 / 4)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```